# NullPointerException for my for loop? java

Tags: java

```
 public static double[] returnArray()
 {
   for (int a=0; a<31; a++) {
     double i = Double.valueOf(days[a]);
      dataArray[a]=i;
   }    
   return(dataArray);   
 }
```

`days[]` is a array of string and `static double[] dataArray` is declared

and it says i got `NullPointerException` at `double i = Double.valueOf(days[a]);`? 
please help,

Comment: where do you initialize your days and dataArray ?

Comment: Can you please show your code to initialize days[] ?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the days var inside this method?

Comment: Most likely your `days` array has not been fully populated.  Though it's certainly possible that you never even created the array for `days`.  You did not provide nearly enough info to be any more specific than that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html - specifically, the part about creating/initializing.

Answer (score 3):

Check there are values in days[a] before you do

```
double i = Double.valueOf(days[a]);
```

My suspicion is that days like days[30] might have no value inside sometimes.

Comment: `days[31]` should never be accessed =)

Answer (score 0):

```
double i = Double.valueOf(days[a] != null ? days[a] : "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

On which iteration does it give a NullPointer Exception?  If it's on the first iteration (a=0) then you probably don't have access to the arrays in that method.  If it's not until (a=30) then maybe it's because you're working with the month of February (28-29 days) so a[29] and a[30] are both null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `days[]` has been initialized. This would cause your problem:

```
private String[] days;
```

or

```
days = null;
```